# Geting SIGBUS (Bus error) @ 0 (0)killed by SIGBUS (core dumped) in Redhat

Tags: linux, gdb, coredump

I have process that works perfectly in the same machine in 2 accounts but when i copy the process to other account and run the process im getting core dump.
when i run the process with strace in the end im getting :

> --- SIGBUS (Bus error) @ 0 (0) ---
>   +++ killed by SIGBUS (core dumped) +++

when i open the core dump im getting :

```
#0  0x000000360046fed3 in malloc_consolidate () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00000036004723fd in _int_malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x000000360047402a in malloc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x00000036004616ba in __fopen_internal () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000fe9652 in LogMngr::OpenFile (this=0x2aaaaad17010, iLogIndex=0) at LogMngr.c:801
```

i can see it something with opening the file for logging , but why it only in one account and in the other is fine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a SIGBUS from an unaligned memory access .  Are you using something  like mmap, shared memory regions, or something similar ?

Comment: On Linux/x86 and x86_64 (where the OP likely is), SIGBUS can *not* result from unaligned access.

Answer (score 1):

Any core dump inside malloc always indicates heap corruption, and heap corruption in general is sneaky like that: it may never show up on machine A, sometimes show up on machine B, and always show up on machine C.

[Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) will likely point you straight at the problem.